# pylint: How to disable max line length limit for long import statements

Tags: pylint

Is there any convenient way to disable max line length limit for import statements, such as by setting rc file?

pylint always report: **C0301:Line too long (108/100).**

But according to [Google Style Guide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#32-line-length), it's fine to not limit line length for long import statements.